# How to get simple url var with Razor MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 3 partials views in a same view and i want get the param for load the good List for put in the good partial.

URL type : myWebSite.com/BigView#View1

I juste want get "View1" parameter.

Note: i ve tried Request.Path but that take only the path, not params ^^

Comment: Satpal : I can't use myWebSite.com/BigView/View1 because no refreshing the page is very important. I ve try to put a parameter like ?View=1 but not work as well with Request.Params['View'] ...

Comment: @timbjames : No, i don't want use this solution before testing it with razor, not a duplicate ^^

Comment: @E.H Your question is basically "How do I get the Location Hash on the server side". That Answer explains that you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not read the hash on the server-side during the page load, because *the hash never gets sent to the server*. Hence, Satpal's suggestion about using URLs such as `/BigView/View1` is the way to go.

Then you go on to say that "not refreshing is very important". For that, you might want to look in to [HTML5 PushState](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate) -- basically, it's a way to update the browser URL in a way that's compatible with URLs like that, without doing full-page reloads.